# How to integrate magento sample data with magento?

Tags: magento-1.7, magento

I have installed magento on ubuntu using magento-1.7.0.2.zip. I have also downloaded magento sample data magento-sample-data-1.6.1.0.tar.gz . But I can't integrate this sample data with my magento installation.

Please somebody help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a [guide on how to install it](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/installing-the-sample-data-for-magento)

Main thing that you should know that you need to extract magento sample data (.sql file and media folder) then put media folder into your magento installation and import .sql file into your empty database **before** you will run Magento installation wizard, otherwise you won't be able to successfully install sample data

Answer (score 0):

This is simplest ways i checked out all of above answer are complicated

1.install the sample database (mysql) file from sample data.

---

2.copy catlog folder from media in sample data and paste into your magento project.

---

3.if on windows no problem of folder permission other have to check for there specific way .